# Drawing Rectangles from a List

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am trying to create some basic rectangles on my map.

This is my MapBounderies class:

```
public int boundY, boundX, boundWidth, boundLength;
    public Texture2D rectTexture;
    public Rectangle boundRectangle;

    List<MapBounderies> boundsList = new List<MapBounderies>();

    public MapBounderies(Rectangle bRectangle, int intX, int intY, int intWidth, int intLength)
    {
        boundY = intY;
        boundX = intX;
        boundWidth = intWidth;
        boundLength = intLength;
    }

    public void Load(ContentManager Content)
    {
        rectTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("black colour");
    }

    public void AddToList(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        boundsList.Add(new MapBounderies(new Rectangle(), 100, 100, 100, 100));
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        foreach (MapBounderies boundries in boundsList)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(rectTexture, new Rectangle(boundries.boundX, boundries.boundY, boundries.boundWidth, boundries.boundLength), Color.White);
        }
    }
```

And this is the error I am getting in my main game code when I try to create a new "MapBounderies":

```
MapBounderies mapBounderies = new MapBounderies();
```

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'bRectangle' of 'MapBounderies.MapBounderies(Rectangle, int, int, int, int)'

I am new to xna and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put in a default constructor? `public MapBounderies(){}`

Comment: where do i put this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And this is the error I am getting in my main game code when I try to create a new "MapBounderies"
>
> **There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'bRectangle' of 'MapBounderies.MapBounderies(Rectangle, int, int, int, int)'**

---

The reason for this error is because you don't have a default constructor, the only signature you have from the code you provided is:

```
 public MapBounderies(Rectangle bRectangle, int intX, int intY, int intWidth, int intLength)
```

As you can see, it takes 5 parameters and you don't have another one that is empty. So to fix, just create another constructor with no parameters.

```
 public MapBoundaries(){}
```

Now you can create an instance of `MapBoundaries` that doesn't take any parameters.

```
 MapBounderies mapBounderies = new MapBounderies();
```